# Apache2 not running on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, apache2

Apache was working fine on my server until I started using gitlab to manage my files. I tried to restart apache and I'm getting the following error

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

I checked my logs and this is the error I see

```
[Thu Jul 23 17:00:26.511870 2015] [core:warn] [pid 32588] AH00111:
Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined [Thu Jul 23
17:00:26.512033 2015] [core:warn] [pid 32588] AH00111: Config variable
${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined  [Thu Jul 23 17:00:26.512057 2015]
[core:warn] [pid 32588] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is
not defined  [Thu Jul 23 17:00:26.512068 2015] [core:warn] [pid 32588]
AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined [Thu Jul
23 17:00:26.512108 2015] [core:warn] [pid 32588] AH00111: Config
variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined [Thu Jul 23 17:00:26.516040
2015] [core:warn] [pid 32588:tid 140305255098240] AH00111: Config
variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined [Thu Jul 23 17:00:26.516255
2015] [core:warn] [pid 32588:tid 140305255098240] AH00111: Config
variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined [Thu Jul 23 17:00:26.516283
2015] [core:warn] [pid 32588:tid 140305255098240] AH00111: Config
variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined AH00526: Syntax error on
line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Invalid Mutex directory in
argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Please help. I've been stuck on this for days.

Answer (score 1):

Those errors are saying:

- there is already a web server running on port 80, so you can't start another one
- Apache can't find its PID or lock files, because it's missing some configuration and doesn't know where to look

What I think is happening:

- The other web server already running on port 80 *is Apache itself*.  The reason it can't recognise itself is that it can't find its PID file, so it can't tell that Apache is already running.

For a service to be able to restart or stop itself with scripts, it needs to keep a record somewhere of which process it is running as.  This is stored in a PID file.  The PID file tells the restart/stop script which process the service is already running under, allowing it to be stopped.  Without it, the restart/stop script doesn't even know that the service is already running, let alone which process it's running as.

You need to check your Apache configuration directory, as something may be missing or corrupt.  If you do not find the cause and are desperate, keep a record of any customisations you've made to Apache configuration, then purge and reinstall Apache, then restore your customisations by hand.

Is it possible that this was caused by gitlab?  It's *possible* though it's not certain.  Some software likes to add files to Apache's configuration under, for example, `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`.  Check that directory for anything that looks like it might have been added by gitlab or other third party software.

Answer (score 0):

All those variables are defined in `/etc/apache2/envvars` in my server.  Check for the existence of that file and that it is set up properly. I had to make some minor changes to it, I think, but pretty much use it as-downloaded.